# How to sendKeys() using/from a python dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, protractor

Something like;

`element(by.model('formData.name')).sendKeys('David Cameron');`

I am trying to find a way to test my admin side when a user signs up. Somewhere I'll have to use `expect` (to check whether entry was submitted to backend) but I want to use a python dictionary of about 10 names where the protractor test selects a name at `random` to `sendKeys()`. How do I establish the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by creating javaScript objects straight away in my testing *spec.js file e.g for 3 random people (objects);

Inside my **sell-spec.js** file;

```
var random = function(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
}

var users = [];
var user1 = {
    name : "Jacob",
    tel : "123",
    email: "1@1.com",
    reg: "1234",
    vin : "2345"
};
var user2 = {
    name : "Jacob2",
    tel : "1232",
    email: "1@12.com",
    reg: "12342",
    vin : "23452"
};
var user3 = {
    name : "Jacob3",
    tel : "1233",
    email: "1@13.com",
    reg: "12343",
    vin : "23453"
};

users.push(user1);
users.push(user2);
users.push(user3);

var selectedUserIndex = random();
selectedUser = users[selectedUserIndex]

element(by.model('formData.name')).sendKeys(selectedUser.name);
element(by.model('formData.cell')).sendKeys(selectedUser.tel);
```

and in my other (admin) spec **admin-spec.js** file;

```
expect(element.all(by.binding('name')).first().getText()).toEqual('Name: ' + seller_details.selectedUser.name );
expect(element.all(by.binding('cell')).first().getText()).toEqual('Cell: ' + seller_details.selectedUser.tel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump your Python dictionary into a JSON file via, for example, [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump), then you can import the JSON file and set the `browser.params` in `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8'));

    browser.params.names = obj;
},
```

Then, you can use `browser.params.names` in your test. To pick up a random value from an array, see this topic: [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array).

Comment: thanks @alecxe.. I implemented an easier js objects after a colleague showed me how to. Your method worked too ;)